# How to manage conditional components with using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose you have below `index.js` code:

```
const App = memo(props => {

    return (
        <Layout>
        // you can consider below code as a switch case 
        {
          {
            'NO_SESSION': <Login />,
            'NOTCONFIRMED_SESSION': <Confirm />
            'CONFIRMED_SESSION': <Home />
          }[sessionState]
        }
        </Layout>
    );
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The `sessionState` is result of some logic depends on `IndexedDB`. Code is something like this:

```
const getSessionState = () => {
   if(// there is no session) 
      return "NO_SESSION"
   else if(// there is not confirmed session)
      return "NOTCONFIRMED_SESSION"
   else if(// there is confirmed session)
      return "CONFIRMED_SESSION"
}
```

So my questions:

> Is it reasonable to do it using `react-hooks`?
>
> If so how to implement?

Comment: How to approach this really depends on the logic in the `if(...)` clauses and when it should be re-evaluated. Are you passing in something with events to subscribe to? Or is it static and won't change over the lifecycle of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes hooks can be used, but the more appropriate question you should be asking is whether you should use component state or context. In the case of global state, context makes more sense as you might need that state in downstream components.

You could store that state in context and read the logged-in state using `useContext`.

Comment: `useContext` is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks. Also if you could extend your answer with a sample implementation, it would be great for newbie like me. I can rewrite my question to more clear.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that